# Attempting to convert a time_t data type to have (dd/mm/yyyy) format C++

Tags: c++, time

My question is pretty much in the title. I have a function call with a parameter of type `time_t`, and I need to initialize a variable to today's date, month, and year, and send it via the argument. For example,

```
void WebCall(time_t TodaysDate)
```

Where `TodaysDate` is the populated variable with the format `DD/MM/YYYY` with the slashes included. Is this possible? I can't change the data type from `time_t` to `SYSTEMTIME` or anything else. This is coded in C++. Any Ideas?

Comment: Google doesn't link to a single piece of relevant info?

Comment: Are you sure about t_time? Maybe time_t?

Comment: If `t_time` is some homegrown type we won't be able to help without more specifics.

Comment: I apologize for that. time_t is the data type I was referring to

Answer (score 1):

If you mean `time_t`, you can format it using `gmtime` and `strftime`:

```
time_t TodaysDate= ...;
struct tm * ptm= gmtime(&time);
char buffer[80];
strftime(buffer, 80, "%d/%m/%Y", ptm);
```

Comment: Sorry guys, yes I meant time_t. So in this code, I could pass the variable ptm to the function? Thanks for the response

Answer (score 1):

`time_t` is "unix time" and is [the number of seconds elapsed since 00:00 hours, Jan 1, 1970 UTC](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/time_t/).  As MSN answered you can convert that to a date using `gmtime`, [for most common purposes, UTC is synonymous with GMT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).  You didn't specify in the question but if you need the local date use `localtime` instead of `gmtime`.  Here's a function that'll do that for you and return a std::string:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <string>

std::string time_to_local_date( time_t utc )
{
    struct tm *now = localtime(&utc);
    char buffer[80];
    strftime(buffer, 80, "%d/%m/%Y", now);
    return std::string(buffer);
}
```